# What does it mean for tensoring to be exact?

Tags: tensor-products

I read a phrase saying that tensoring $\mathbb{Q}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ is exact. What does it mean for tensoring to be exact?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_module

Answer (score 1):

Each exact sequence 
$$
  \cdots \to A_1 \to A_2 \to A_3 \to \cdots 
$$
of $\mathbb Z$-modules is mapped to an exact sequence 
$$
  \cdots \to A_1 \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Q \to A_2 \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Q \to A_3 \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Q \to \cdots 
$$